# List of Dictionary Manipulation in python

Tags: python

I have a list of the folowing form:

```
oldlist = [{'x': 1, 'y':2},{'x':2, 'y':2},{'x':1, 'y':3},{'x':1, 'y':2},{'x':3, 'y':4}]
```

to be converted into

```
final = [{'x':1,'y':[2,3,2],'count':3},{'x':2,'y':[2],'count':1},{'x':3,'y':[4],'count':1}]
```

I have tried

```
oldlist = [{'x': {'a':1,'b':2}, 'y':2},{'x':{'a':6,'b':7}, 'y':2},{'x':{'a':1,'b':2}, 'y':3},{'x':{'a':1,'b':2}, 'y':2},{'x':{'a':10,'b':11}, 'y':4}]  
list1=[]  
list2=[]  
list3=[]  
s = set([d['x'] for d in oldlist])  
news=list(s)  
for item in oldlist:  
if item['x'] == news[0]:  
      list1.append(item['y'])  

if item['x'] == news[1]:  
      list2.append(item['y'])  

if item['x'] == news[2]:  
      list3.append(item['y'])  
final=[]  
dic1 = {'x':news[0],'y':list1,'count':len(list1)}  
dic2 = {'x':news[1],'y':list2,'count':len(list2)}  
dic3 = {'x':news[2],'y':list3,'count':len(list3)}  
final.append(dic1)  
final.append(dic2)  
final.append(dic3)  
print final
```

Is there a simpler way to do it? Plus here I knew that x can have only three values so I created three variables list1, list2 and list3. What if x can have several other values and I have to find out a similar list of dictionaries like final! It should also work for strings!

Comment: You can make a `list` from the `set` with `s_list = sorted(s)`. (Or just `s_list = list(s)` if you don't care about it being sorted.)

Comment: @leekaiinthesky That will work for this example but not for others that can have various other values of x.

Answer (score 4):

You can collect the dicts to [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) where key is `x` from original dicts and value is list of related `y` values. Then use list comprehension to generate the final result:

```
from collections import defaultdict

l = [{'x':1, 'y':2},{'x':2, 'y':2},{'x':1, 'y':3},{'x':1, 'y':2},{'x':3, 'y':4}]
res = defaultdict(list)
for d in l:
    res[d['x']].append(d['y'])
final = [{'x': k, 'y': v, 'count': len(v)} for k, v in res.items()] # [{'y': [2, 3, 2], 'x': 1, 'count': 3}, {'y': [2], 'x': 2, 'count': 1}, {'y': [4], 'x': 3, 'count': 1}]
```

Comment: This is the error that I'm getting on running your code. TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

Comment: @glitterati Did you run the solution as such or did you modify it? Could you try to copy & paste the example to separate file and try running it?

Comment: I modified it a little. Actually the x field in  the oldlist my example is a dictionary. Hence the error. Can you please suggest what to do in a case where x is a dict item and y is the same. I can modify the question accordingly if you want!

Comment: Convert `dict` to `frozenset` of tuples and use that as a key: `frozenset(x.items())`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37583117/list-of-dictionary-manipulation-in-python-typeerror-unhashable-type-dict

Answer (score 1):

```
x_list = [item['x'] for item in list1]
set_value = set(x_list)
final_lst = []

for i in set_value:
   d = {}
   d['x'] = i
   d['count'] = x_list.count(i)
   d['y'] = []
   for item in list1:
       if item['x'] == d['x']:
          d['y'].append(item['y'])
   final_lst.append(d)  
print ("Final List", final_lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I used a little trick here to do the job, it's not the most pythonic way but it still gets the answer you want.
The problem was indexing? So a changed s to t, where t is a list and changed the end of the code because you have to put the keys on your dictionaries as strings, so x become 'x' and so on.

See the whole code below:

```
lista = [{'x':1, 'y':2},{'x':2, 'y':2},{'x':1, 'y':3},{'x':1, 'y':2},{'x':3, 'y':4}]  


list1=[]
list2=[]
list3=[]
for d in lista:
    print(d)
s = set([d['x'] for d in lista])
t = []
for element in s: #turn t into a list which has the same ordering as s
    t.append(element)
for item in lista:
    if item['x'] == t[0]:
          list1.append(item['y'])

    if item['x'] == t[1]:
          list2.append(item['y'])

    if item['x'] == t[2]:
          list3.append(item['y'])
final=[]
dic1 = {'x':t[0],'y':list1,'count':len(list1)}
dic2 = {'x':t[1],'y':list2,'count':len(list2)}
dic3 = {'x':t[2],'y':list3,'count':len(list3)}
final.append(dic1)
final.append(dic2)
final.append(dic3)   
print(final)
```

Comment: This works for this example but not for others where distinct values of x might be more than 3. That was my question in the first place.

Comment: Oh, so change a little bit the logic: (Sorry, I clicked "Enter" wrong, I'm still thinking about how can I solve this).